# Jenkins master throwing java.io.IOException when running pipeline in swarm client

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-agent

Im trying to run a pipeline job in an agent which is using swarm client. The job runs fine but im getting a lot of error messages in the log like below:

```
Cannot contact tst_db2: java.io.IOException: Remote call on Channel to /XX.XX.XX.XXX failed
```

*(actual IP address replaced with XX)*

In my observation the master is throwing this errors while waiting for the script that is running in the client. Again, the pipeline job run perfectly except that im getting this error on the pipeline logs.

Below is my pipeline script:

```
pipeline {
    agent none
    stages {
        stage('Recreate DB') {
            agent { label 'tst_db2'}
            steps {
                checkout([$class: 'SubversionSCM', 
                  additionalCredentials: [], 
                  excludedCommitMessages: '', 
                  excludedRegions: '', 
                  excludedRevprop: '', 
                  excludedUsers: '', 
                  filterChangelog: false, 
                  ignoreDirPropChanges: false, 
                  includedRegions: '', 
                  locations: [[credentialsId: 'a84f7197-929a-437e-9aac-ca09fcd4c63a', 
                               depthOption: 'infinity', 
                               ignoreExternalsOption: true, 
                               local: '', 
                               remote: 'svn://XXXXX/XXX/tags/CR/Rebuild_VCRDWD01']], 
                  workspaceUpdater: [$class: 'CheckoutUpdater']])  

                 sh 'Rebuild_VCRDWD01/recreate_db.sh'
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

Is there anyway we can get rid of this errors?

**Environment**:

Jenkins Version : 2.32.2

Running on Windows Server 2012 R2

Swarm Client 3.3 on AIX 7.1 and JDK 8

Also raised a Jenkins issue: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-42428

Comment: You should cross-link your Jenkins issue with this post so you make it 100% clear that you've asked this question in multiple venues.

Comment: I have updated my question based on your comment. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

A user in the ticket mentioned previously reported that they were able to get rid of the error by downgrading the "Pipeline: Nodes and Processes" plugin in Jenkins to 2.8 - available from [here](http://updates.jenkins-ci.org/download/plugins/workflow-durable-task-step/). I was able to get rid of the problem as well by doing that.  Unfortunately there are a number of other plugins I have installed that are dependent on version 2.10.  I'm not keen on backleveling all of those, so guess I'm going to have to live with this as an annoyance until there's an official fix from the plugin maintainer.  Hopefully that will be soon.